# Default Google Map Marker from Server Generated GEOJson

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson

I have a mysql database that has all point based geo data. I have the sever generate the GEOJson and serve it over a Flask based API.

I am using the Android Google Maps SDK. Would I be able to simply show the default marker from that data?